# Confused with Java Wildcards in combination with using keyword "super"

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Assuming we have this hierarchy of classes.

`Object` <-- `Class A` <-- `Class B` <-- `Class C`

If I have

```
List<? super B> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Why can I only add objects to "myList" which are Instance of class B or the subclass C? That doesn't make any sense to me. I thought if I use "? super B" in my wildcard (or the same with generics) I can only put in objects which are B or super classes of B. I'm absolutely confused and I hope someone can help me to understand this stuff.

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't :/ I just don't understand why i can't add A to B, if the wildcard is <? super B>.

Comment: Using "? super B" in your wildcard DOESN'T mean "you can only put in objects which are B or superclasses of B". It means you can only put in objects of B. The purpose of declaring it as <? super B> instead of <B>, is because a list<A> is also capable of taking Bs, so you don't want your type to be limited to list<B>. A list<A> is a valid <? super B> (consumer of Bs). A list<Object> is also valid.